# Starting tasks in a for loop and then doing waitall on all of them

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I saw couple of posts on this... but most people are manually creating tasks rather than receiving it from an API.

I have this code

```
        Task[] tasks = new Task[companyCount];
        // start all threads
        for(int i = 0; i < companyCount; i++) {
            string input = GetNextCompanyRecord(i);
            string token = GetUserToken();
            HttpClient client = GetHttpClient();
            StringContent content = CreateStringContent(input);
            var x = client.PostAsync(companyUrlString, content).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
            tasks[i] = x;
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

the objective is that I start the task for each record in a for loop and then when all tasks are started ... doing a single waitall.

problem is that I cannot assign the x variable to the task array.

The PostAsync method is not returning me the Task. instead it is returning ConfiguredTaskAwaitable. But my hope was that I will get Task and I will be able to add that to my array and then do a waitall.

Comment: Remove the unnecessary `.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)` and you're golden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do it like this:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage>[] tasks = new Task<HttpResponseMessage>[companyCount];
for(int i = 0; i < companyCount; i++)
{
    string input = GetNextCompanyRecord(i);
    string token = GetUserToken();
    HttpClient client = GetHttpClient();
    StringContent content = CreateStringContent(input);
    var x = client.PostAsync(companyUrlString, content);
    tasks[i] = x;
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

But, perhaps a cleaner way would be to do this:

```
var tasks =
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, companyCount)
    let input = GetNextCompanyRecord(i)
    let token = GetUserToken()
    let client = GetHttpClient()
    let content = CreateStringContent(input)
    select client.PostAsync(companyUrlString, content);

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Or even better yet:

```
using (var client = GetHttpClient())
{
    var tasks =
        from i in Enumerable.Range(0, companyCount)
        let input = GetNextCompanyRecord(i)
        let token = GetUserToken()
        let content = CreateStringContent(input)
        select client.PostAsync(companyUrlString, content);

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: After doing the WaitAll, now how will you get all the HttpResponseMessage from each task?

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch - Before doing the `WaitAll` assign the tasks to an array and then wait on that array. Then you can use the same array to retrieve all of the response messages. Just get the `Value` from each task. The important thing here is that you must use the same array of tasks. If you try to use the `tasks` query instead you'll create a new set of tasks.

Answer (score 3):

`PostAsync` *is* returning a `Task` (a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`, to be precise), but then you're calling `ConfigureAwait` on it, which returns a `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`.

Try getting a reference to the task first, and then calling `ConfigureAwait`.

```
var task = client.PostAsync(companyUrlString, content);
ConfiguredTaskAwaitable awaitable = task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
tasks[i] = task;
```

Also, consider:

- removing the call to `ConfigureAwait`, since you don't seem to need it anyway.
- changing your array from `Task[]` to `Task<HttpResponseMessage>[]`, if you want to retrieve the tasks' results when they're done.

Comment: Although lacking in explanation, Enigmativity's answer is much better, you should accept his instead.

Comment: ok. thanks. I had seen your answer first so had marked it as answer.